# Anybody having issues with sync framework v2.1 when initializing the database?

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

Some of the tables that I am trying to intialize are anywhere from 2 to 16 million records.  I started a sync last night at 5pm and STILL waiting.  How is this framework a viable option for the real world?  Anyone having the same experience?

These are the steps that I took...

1. Populate the client database with all data from source using SSIS.
2. Provision client db and source db.2.
3. Sync client with "download only".3.
4. Wait for eternity.

Comment: I'm actually looking to hire someone to write an article on using this stuff in production. If there are any takers, send an email to jonathan@infoq.com

Answer (score 0):

Well lets analyze what you just said:
`Some of the tables that I am trying to intialize are anywhere from 2 to 16 million records.`

Some meaning several meaning more than 1 and millions of records.  You have given us no information about the schema so I am going to assume here that they are all blobs of 500k each.  That will solve that problem.  I don't see how synchronizing what I am guessing to be 100's of millions of records in 24 hours that undoubtedly have disjoint data types is that big of a deal.

Comment: I am aware of this statement's meaning.  The issue is why is there not a better way to create a sync baseline (with its tracking tables) to have its metadata updated to know it has the latest possible data in an easier fashion?  Maybe I am missing a procedure to show me a better way to sync for intialization (I will place the steps I took in my original post).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sync framework is quite slow especially if you have not batched your rows. It is much better to use a backup of your server to initialize the database, or in case they are not symmetrical, do the sync over a fast network connection (like LAN instead of internet).

Here I am assuming the bottleneck is the bandwidth (as has been for me most of the times) - in case the CPU/memory usage is causing issues then obviously we need other alternatives.

However the framework is viable in the real world, when you expect frequent synchronization and hence the amount of data changed is not much. Especially useful if you want to put specific logic or filter data out (for eg sales person getting sales data only related to his accounts/region instead of all the data).

Comment: I am actually doing the initialization now to create a backup which would be restored on about 100 clients.  What I have is the syncs being batched as files by the source which are then being used by the client to update the client's db.  The problem is timing for creating this initialization.  My concern is if we ever had to change the schema or need to recreate a baseline backup, it would need some serious prep time.  There has to be a better way in regards to creating and populating the tracking tables.